# Plotting a hard integral describing voltage in an electric circuit

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, physics, code-review

I have an electric circuit and the function I want to plot is the following:

$$\int_0^t\left|\text{u}\sin\left(\omega x+\varphi\right)\right|\cdot\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{1+\text{sL}\left(\text{sC}+\frac{1}{\text{R}_3}\right)}\right]_{t-x}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Where $\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\cdot\right]_{t-x}$ is the inverse Laplace transform and all the other constants are real and positive.

Now, the code I want to use is the following:

```
    u = 230*Sqrt[2];
    ω = 2*Pi*50;
    Φ = Pi/46;
    L = 45*10^(-7);
    c = 59*10^(-6);
    R3 = 1/10;
    Plot[Integrate[
      Abs[ u Sin[ω x + Φ]]*
       InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(1 + s L (s c + (1/R3))), s, t - x], {x, 
       0, t}], {t, 0, 4 (2 Pi/ω)}]
```

But it takes forever to run the code.

How can I improve the code so that it runs quicker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Abs` makes this integrand hard to evaluate for the system and it is more straightforward to obtain a numerical integral. Defining first

```
iLT[t_, x_] = InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(1 + s L (s c + (1/R3))), s, t - x]//FullSimplify
```

one can see that it takes vary small values in the interesting region and in order to avoid false numerical integration we specify `WorkingPrecision` and `PrecisionGoal`:

```
nint[t_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[ Abs[u Sin[ω x + Φ]] iLT[t, x], {x, 0, t}, 
              WorkingPrecision -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

Now we can plot the function in a satisfactory precision:

```
Plot[ nint[t], {t, 0, 4(2 Pi/ω )}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
      WorkingPrecision -> 20] // Quiet
```

[image]

It takes about $2$ minutes to evaluate, nevertheless to receive a better plot it takes roughly $15$ minutes:

```
Plot[nint[t], {t, 0, 4 (2 Pi/ω )}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"] // Quiet
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

it is having hard time with exact integral. Replace with numerical.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

u   = 230*Sqrt[2];
ω   = 2*Pi*50;
Φ   = Pi/46;
L   =  45*10^(-7);
c   = 59*10^(-6);
R3  = 1/10;

tmp       = InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(1 + s*L*(s*c + (1/R3))), s, t - x];
Integrand = Abs[u*Sin[ω*x + Φ]]*tmp;
f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Integrand, {x, 0, t}]

Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 4*((2 Pi)/ω)}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

When `Plot` is too slow, I fall back on a `Table` and a `ListLinePlot` which means you can control how many points to plot:

```
u = 230*Sqrt[2];
ω = 2*Pi*50;
Φ = Pi/46;
L = 45*10^(-7);
c = 59*10^(-6);
R3 = 1/10;
ilt = InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(1 + s*L*(s*c + (1/R3))), s, τ];

intg[t_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[Abs[u*Sin[ω*x + Φ]]*(ilt /. {τ -> t - x}), {x, 0, t}];

ListLinePlot@ParallelTable[{t, intg[t]}, {t, 0, 4*((2 Pi)/ω), .001}]
```

[image: waveform]

Notice I did **not** compute the inverse Laplace transform against $t-x$. I computed it against a temporary variable $\tau$ then replaced this with $t-x$ in the integrand. It's not clear to me why doing this produced the waveform plot while the other method didn't - perhaps if somebody knows why they can comment.

Answer (score 1):

The transformation can be calculated once outside (before) the plot. Replace InverseLaplaceTransform with its result and use NIntegrate instead of Integrate.
Then the plot will be done in a few seconds.

Andreas